# File scan and file move in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program in java that scans each file and then if it ends with a certain extension ( for example .class) moves it in a different folder. I have a certain error that bothers me for a week now. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.nio.file.Files; 
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.File; 



public class file_transfer_alpha_build { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      File baseDir = new File("C:/Users/gp/Desktop/Java") ;
      File destDir = new File("C:/Users/gp/Desktop/Java/test") ;

      File[] files = baseDir.listFiles();
      for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++){
        if (files[i].endsWith(".class")){
            files[i].renameTo(new File(destDir, files[i].getName()));
        }
      }

    }
}
```

The error :

```
file_transfer_alpha_build.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        if (files[i].endsWith(".class")){
                    ^
  symbol:   method endsWith(String)
  location: class File
1 error
```

Comment: Why do you import `java.nio` but never use any of its classes?

Answer (score 5):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong with the code. There is no `endsWith()` method in the `File` class. You need to use `getName` there to get the file's name:

```
if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".class")){
    files[i].renameTo(new File(destDir, files[i].getName()));
}
```